# Почему у MySQL threads_per_sec равно 0?

Tags: mysql, оптимизация

Запустил tuning-primer.sh первый раз - он мне посоветовал включить threads. Включил их в настройках, прошло несколько дней, в результате пишет:

```
   WORKER THREADS
   Current thread_cache_size = 4
   Current threads_cached = 3
   Current threads_per_sec = 0
   Historic threads_per_sec = 0
```

Почему threads_per_sec = 0? Где почитать про это, нужно ли что-то менять?

Comment: http://mysqltips.blogspot.com.by/2007/03/mysql-threads-tunning.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Читать об этом надо в исходнике:

```
mysql_status \'Threads_created\' threads_created1
sleep 1
mysql_status \'Threads_created\' threads_created2

mysql_status \'Threads_cached\' threads_cached
mysql_status \'Uptime\' uptime
mysql_variable \'thread_cache_size\' thread_cache_size

historic_threads_per_sec=$(($threads_created1/$uptime))
current_threads_per_sec=$(($threads_created2-$threads_created1))
```

https://launchpadlibrarian.net/78745738/tuning-primer.sh

То есть просто запрашиваем количество созданных потоков, спим 1 секунду, запрашиваем снова, находим разницу и выдаем на экран.
Читать ничего не надо. Все хорошо.